# Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 Upgrade to GNOME 3.14 Blank Screen, Can't Login

Tags: gnome

Hi I upgraded my Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 fresh install to Gnome 3.14 by using the gnome team ppas. I'm using a Sony E11 64-bit AMD laptop. After rebooting I was greeted with a blank screen, and I can only login to the terminal. Running `startx` as a normal user or with `sudo` privilege , doesn't help, only when I'm logged in as root (after `sudo -i`)

When I login to the terminal I'm greeted with the following text:

```
systemd-logind[1071]: Failed to start unit user@1000.service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too and I fixed it~

It's because the gdm package is broken.

login to terminal and temporarily change your greeting screen back to lightdm(you can change back to gdm later) by typing this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and select lightdm then`sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot

and you can login normally. If you still want to use gdm as boot screen, reinstall it by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm` and do a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` again.

Please accept my answer if you found it helps, thx ~

Comment: Didn't work... I had to install lightdm though. But it won't let me login. The password entry box is not visible, though it accepts passwords. Once you try  to login though, it throws you back out to the login screen. GDM is still blank.

Comment: It kind of works, at least now I can login. GDM still borks, though. Thank you!

Comment: yaa switching to lightdm fixed the black screen issue. Thanks.