# Install GNOME Desktop Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

How can I install Gnome Desktop on Ubuntu 15.04 with unity? Don't want to make a new clean install-- Any idea? Can't find any information about it!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Log out and open a terminal on TTY1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo service gdm restart
```

---

As [@Exocom](https://askubuntu.com/users/411563/exocom) said, the following step is not necessary.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Then choose the desktop you want and you can log in again.

Comment: As far as I can see it, step 2) and 3) are not necessary. You will be asked to choose your display manager on step 1) and after logging out gdm will be started automatically.

Comment: @Exocom Thx, I will add your comment.

Comment: The gdm restart is necessary after all, sorry about the wrong information in the comment before. I corrected the answer accordingly (and tried it a few times this time ;-))!

Comment: What if I do it in terminal without logging out. Any cons?

Comment: Thanks @A.B. but on 15.10 if you see black screen on login then you can switch back to lightdm. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/571252/ubuntu-gnome-14-10-upgrade-to-gnome-3-14-blank-screen-cant-login

Comment: @A.B. anyways is it possible to use gdm and still not get the black desktop screen? I like gdm login.

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Choose "gdm" when asked.

In case not being asked execute :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

To restart the system execute :

```
sudo reboot
```

Rebooting after installing a new DE is **not necessary**, however some say it is **recommended**.

**Update** :

To make up your own mind on this topic, read [When is it necessary to reboot an Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672223/when-is-it-necessary-to-reboot-an-ubuntu-system)

Comment: Why reboot?! That's not Windows.

Comment: No, `sudo service gdm restart`.

Comment: Where is this written?

Comment: ubuntu 15 has its own set of issues, ubuntu is going the windows way and not working of the box for basic stuff like wifi... so stop getting annoyed at reboot..