# How to remove Gnome desktop from Regular (Unity) Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall, 15.04

Currently have Ubuntu 15.04 with the default Unity desktop environment.  I wanted to try the Gnome environment so I followed the following instructions:

[Install GNOME Desktop Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614657/install-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-15-04)

However, no there are a number of bugs that affect my Unity environment.  For instance, I cannot change my wallpaper from the default one -- right clicking, Unity Tweak Tool, and CCSM do not work.  Also the Super key works intermittently.  There are also still options on the login screen to select the Gnome environments.

What is the best way to remove Gnome and start from scratch?  I've so far tried

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell
```

The script ran but these issues are still apparent after restarting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this short of re-installing.

Comment: In order to restore access to your wallpaper through right-clicking, install GNOME Tweak Tool (it's different from the Unity Tweak Tool).

Answer (score 2):

I did the exact same thing on 15.04 and this is how I got it to reverse.

Log out and open a TTY1 terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 then run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

When asked to, choose "lightdm", then run this

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
```

The last command as you can tell will restart the computer. After this the GNOME boot animation may remain but the rest will be just the way it was before installing the GNOME desktop environment. The "reconfigure lightdm" command changes the login screen back to Ubuntu default by changing the display manager from "gdm" (GNOME Display Manager) back to Ubuntu's official "lightdm". I hope this works for you.