# How and where to report a bug when screen freezes?

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, bug-reporting, fullscreen, gpu-driver

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and when I launch some fullscreen aplications, they randomly (at a given moment) freeze my display. I can move the mouse pointer using the mousepad but neither I can't click nor press a key combination to exit the aplication. If I press Alt+F1 (I think), then I go completely into  CLI. 
My question is, if I suspect that this is a bug from one or more of my repositories, how can I detect wich of them is buggy and how to file this bug (under which package)?

Thanks for your patiente, as I am new at this.

Comment: The combination you pressed is not `Alt+F1`, but `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. It switches you to a virtual terminal, where you could, e.g., run a new graphic session, or to do anything else. To switch back press `Ctrl+Alt+F7` *(though the number isn't mandatory; e.g. on Archlinux graphical session is rather `…F1`)*. The problem looks to me is either drivers or Unity. To pin it down, try installing another DE, or [latest *userspace* drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) *(a note: graphic drivers on Linux are consist of kernel side and userspace, so to check I'd go for DE)*.

Comment: You could also check `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` files for errors *(and perhaps `dmesg`)*, though in my experience in such cases they didn't mention anything useful, but just for the safe case.

Comment: Ah, btw, in your case just for usability you could bind to a button the command `xkill`, it allows you to press with cursor to a window, and the acc. process would be killed *(press Escape to cancel)*.

Comment: Thanks @Hi-Angel , I'll try installing another DE alongside Unity (I think it can be done... like GNOME / Plasma / MATE / Xfce / etc... ) and keep an eye for changes. Right now I'm suspecting from http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-x/vulkan/ubuntu , http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu and https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main , wich I configured trying to solve graphical issues. Funny thing.

Comment: Btw, thanks for that info about log errors and key combinations / binds. I'll definetly try them out.

Comment: Installing Gnome is easy, e.g. [here's an example](http://askubuntu.com/a/614692/266507) *(a correction to the answer: you only need to switch to a VT to do `…gdm restart`. A reboot would work too, of course)*. And I confused a bit: to cancel `xkill` it is "right mouse button", not Escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, and trying to tag my own question with a "freeze" tag which possibly means that this is a bug with a graphic driver, I just found that there are 2 bug reports at *Oibaf's "Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers"*. This bug causes the screen to completly freeze with the exception of the mouse pointer.

> Bug Description
>
> During the installation the computer freezes completely except for the
>   mouse pointer. And even that is stuck with whatever shape it happened
>   to have at the time it froze. The steps I have to cause the freeze are
>   run Ubiquity to start the installation open a terminal, run Ubuntu-bug
>   and let it launch Firefox. It will freeze every time then. Even the
>   consoles (ctrl-alt-f1 etc) are unavailable. What kind of information
>   can I collect and how?

Bug [#1377878](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1377878) for Oibaf's repo and Bug [#55745](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55745) for Xorg Project Team, are related and quite old (reported 2 years and 4 years ago respectively without a fix).
I would suggest, sticking with default Ubuntu drivers, suscribe to #1377878 and wait for a fix.